# How to design four column layout using css only when column widths will be variable?

Tags: html, css

I want a four column layout using CSS only where the width of the columns will act responsively. To understand my problem at first please look at below code:

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
}

.col1 {
  background-color: #89ffa2;
}

.col2 {
  background-color: #b2f0f9;
}

.col3 {
  background-color: #ffa7a7;
}

.col4 {
  background-color: #fff689;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col1">
    This is column 1
  </div>

  <div class="col col2">
    This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2.
  </div>

  <div class="col col3">
    This is column 3. This is column 3. This is column 3. This is column 3. This is column 3. This is column 3.
  </div>

  <div class="col col4">
    This is column 4.
  </div>
</div>
```

In the code above, the width is given as 25%, so it will act responsively as equal width for all the columns. But I don't want this 25%. What I want to achieve is, as column 1 and column 4 is pretty smaller in this case, so column 1 and column 4 will be in the size of their content's width. But as all other columns are beyond the 25% size they will take equal width. Also, the height of all 4 columns will be equal to the height of the column having maximum height. And I want this to be responsive, like when screen size will be smaller, then at some points all 4 columns will have to be in same width. And the column 1 and column 4 is dummy in this case. I want it to be dynamic because which column's content will be greater and which one will be smaller that is not known.

I want it to be like this:

[image]

And when the screen will be resized it may then become like this:

[image]

Is this possible with only CSS? Maybe, I could make myself clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just erase the width, then the cell widths will adjust according to their contents.

And if you want the text in column 1 and 4 not to break, you can add `white-space: no-wrap` to them

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
}

.col1 {
  background-color: #89ffa2;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.col2 {
  background-color: #b2f0f9;
}

.col3 {
  background-color: #ffa7a7;
}

.col4 {
  background-color: #fff689;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col1">
    This is column 1
  </div>

  <div class="col col2">
    This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2.
  </div>

  <div class="col col3">
    This is column 3. This is column 3. This is column 3. This is column 3. This is column 3. This is column 3.
  </div>

  <div class="col col4">
    This is column 4.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I asked that, the texts are dummy and in actual scenario, the size of the columns are unknown, so providing `7em` is making the size fixed. Also, maybe you haven't noticed, your code is not responsive. In some stage of decreasing screen size, the rightmost column gets hidden.

Comment: Then just erase the `width` alltogether (which I did in my snippet now)

Comment: I've already tried this, but in this case the texts for column 1 and column 4 are going in the next line.

Comment: Hmm - that doesn't happen with my snippet above if it's exapanded to the full window and the window is made as small as possible (i.e. around 320px wide)

Comment: Thanks for your try, but this is not I was expecting, when I run your code snippet it gives me something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwLRK.png. But what I want, that is already mentioned in my question as image. `This is column 1` is not in the same line in your case.

Comment: If you mean that the text of column 1 and 4 shouldn't wrap, you can apply `white-space: nowrap;` to the first and last column.

Comment: Well, it's too close to what I want. But I have told that the example is dummy only, not always column 1 and column 4 will be smaller in size, maybe in some case column 2 can be smaller, but if I provide `white-space: nowrap;` to all the columns it will not look good, you know that. So, can't it be done dynamically. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a good old HTML element called `<table>`

you can create table with one row and 4 columns, give it 100% width.

Now format it as your hearth likes and it will automatically adjust width for cells with more text in them.

I guess flexbox is another solution but table will be supported in all browsers

Comment: Flexbox is supported 97.76% of all users but still table is not scary in this situation and has 100% support

Answer (score 0):

Use `max-width` with flexbox. Here is an example:

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.row > .col {
  max-width:25%;
}

.col1 {
  background-color: #89ffa2;
}

.col2 {
  background-color: #b2f0f9;
}

.col3 {
  background-color: #ffa7a7;
}

.col4 {
  background-color: #fff689;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col1">
    This is column 1
  </div>

  <div class="col col2">
    This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2.
  </div>

  <div class="col col3">
    This is column 3. This is column 3. This is column 3. This is column 3. This is column 3. This is column 3.
  </div>

  <div class="col col4">
    This is column 4.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the whole container has become smaller in this case. I wanted that column 1 and column 4 will be in their content's width as they are smaller, but other 2 column will be in same width such that whole container becomes 100% width

Comment: @user12313780 am not sure if i understand all your requirement, but it seems that some of them are contradictory .. can clarify your question to list them point by point and give an example ?

Comment: I've edited my question. Please ask me if you have any more doubt. In your provided answer, the row is not fit to the full width of the screen, that's why I'm having some problem.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
}

.col1 {
  background-color: #89ffa2;
  width: 15%;
}

.col2 {
  background-color: #b2f0f9;
  width: 35%;
}

.col3 {
  background-color: #ffa7a7;
  width: 35%;
}

.col4 {
  background-color: #fff689;
  width: 15%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .col {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 25%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col1">
    This is column 1
  </div>

  <div class="col col2">
    This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2. This is column 2.
  </div>

  <div class="col col3">
    This is column 3. This is column 3. This is column 3. This is column 3. This is column 3. This is column 3.
  </div>

  <div class="col col4">
    This is column 4.
  </div>
</div>
```